# NCurses 65536 Color Pairs

Tags: c++, colors, ncurses, curses

I have compiled NCurses 6.3 with the `--enable-ext-colors` and `--enable-widec` flags.

I then iterate across all background colors, for each foreground color:

```cpp
void initColorPairs()
{
    for (int foregroundId = 0; foregroundId < 255; foregroundId++)
    {
        for (int backgroundId = 0; backgroundId < 255; backgroundId++)
        {
            init_extended_pair(
                getColorPairId(foregroundId, backgroundId),
                foregroundId,
                backgroundId);
        }
    }
};
```

This sets the macro COLOR_PAIRS to 65536.

```cpp
...
std::cout << "initialized color pairs: " << COLOR_PAIRS << std::endl; //displays `initialized color pairs: 65536`
...
```

This is working perfectly.

I have a unique id for every color pair defined by this function:

```cpp
int getColorPairId(int foregroundId, int backgroundId)
{
    return foregroundId + (backgroundId << 8);
};
```

This all appears to work perfectly.
However, when trying to render each of these possible color pairs and printing them next to each other:

```cpp
// visualize
std::string testText = "a";
for (int foregroundId = 0; foregroundId < 255; foregroundId++)
{
    for (int backgroundId = 0; backgroundId < 255; backgroundId++)
    {
        attr_on(COLOR_PAIR(getColorPairId(foregroundId, backgroundId)), NULL);
        mvprintw(foregroundId, backgroundId, testText.c_str());
    }
}
```

Instead of ending up with a screen full of each foreground color against each background color I end up with this:
[image: block of text of the letter "A", with only the foreground color changing across characters]

It should be changing the background color with each character, but it only seems to change the foreground.

Strangely, if the colorId construction is reversed (foreground shifted over 8 bits instead of background), the *background* iterates instead of the foreground!

```cpp
int getColorPairId(int foregroundId, int backgroundId)
{
    return backgroundId + (foregroundId << 8);
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without using the extended colors in the library interface, color pairs are limited to 32767 (signed 16-bit numbers).

That **`NULL`** in

```
attr_on(COLOR_PAIR(getColorPairId(foregroundId, backgroundId)), NULL);
```

should be used to pass the value of an integer (more than 16-bits) for the color pair, as mentioned in the [*Extensions*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html#h2-EXTENSIONS) section of the manual page, e.g.,

> - For  functions  which modify the color, e.g., **`wattr_set`**, if opts is
>   set it is treated as a pointer to int, and used to  set  the  color
>   pair instead of the short pair parameter.

But in expanding the answer, I see that these calls are overlooked (probably because the color-pair is not an explicit parameter to these, but is a derived value within the body of the function):

> The remaining functions which have opts, but do not  manipulate  color, e.g., **`wattr_on`** and **`wattr_off`** are not used by this implementation except to check that they are NULL.

The ncurses-examples (demo and test-programs) include a few using `attr_on` (see [*`README`*](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/test/README#L262)), but those calls aren't using this particular extension ([`dots_xcurses`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/test/dots_xcurses.c#L252) would be a good place to do that – optionally of course).

[`picsmap`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/test/picsmap.c#L1598) uses the feature via [`setcchar`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h2-EXTENSIONS):

- source for [`wattr_on`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/ncurses/base/lib_wattron.c#L57)
- source for [`setcchar`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/ncurses/widechar/lib_cchar.c#L63), using the macro [**`set_extended_pair`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/ncurses/new_pair.h#L78)

```
    #define set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair) \
        if ((opts) != NULL) { \
            color_pair = *(const int*)(opts); \
        }
```

That macro **is** used in other functions (to allow those to be conditionally compiled with/without the feature):

```
new_pair.h:71:#define set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair) \                     
new_pair.h:78:#define set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair) \                     
base/lib_chgat.c:64:    set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair);                    
base/lib_colorset.c:54:    set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair);                 
base/lib_slkatr_set.c:58:    set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair);               
widechar/lib_cchar.c:63:    set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair);                
widechar/lib_vid_attr.c:101:    set_extended_pair(opts, color_pair);
```

For `wattr_on.c`, the [chunk](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/74b10d4a30eec8feb66a4b94a72da65be0048447/ncurses/base/lib_wattron.c#L57)

```
if_EXT_COLORS({
    if (at & A_COLOR)
        win->_color = PairNumber(at);
});
```

(which extracts a color pair from the attribute parameter) would look like

```
if_EXT_COLORS({
    if (at & A_COLOR) {
        win->_color = PairNumber(at);
        set_extended_pair(opts, win->_color);
    }
});
```

`wattr_set` is handled properly:

```
#define wattr_set(win,a,p,opts) \                                               
        (NCURSES_OK_ADDR(win) \                                                 
         ? ((void)((win)->_attrs = ((a) & ~A_COLOR), \                          
                   (win)->_color = (opts) ? *(int *)(opts) : (p)), \            
            OK) \                                                               
         : ERR)
```

(No change would be needed for `wattr_off`, of course).  X/Open Curses assumes that the attribute parameter *`at`* of `wattr_on` does not include bits for a color pair.  ncurses does do this (because it uses the same layout for the attributes in narrow/wide libraries), so providing a use for the *`opts`* parameter is consistent – for ncurses.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What would be an example of this? I might be being naive but I just moved the first argument to the second (as a pointer instead of course). Replaced the first with NULL. And now *none* of the characters have color. (Also I am running xterm-256color)

Like so: `int pairId = COLOR_PAIR(getColorPairId(foregroundId, backgroundId)); attr_on(NULL, &pairId);`

Comment: hmm - no (I'll amend the answer)

Comment: Thank you again for putting in the work to answer this. I understand how it works now.

But I still don't understand why it doesn't work for me. I have `--enable-ext-colors` and `--enable-widec` both defined. Why it wouldn't be using those extended functions then? I also have CURSES_NEED_WIDE in my CMakeLists.txt AND am importing from <ncursesw/ncurses.h> but I'm not sure if that's necessary.